# AWS CodeDeploy --Deploy different web.config

Tags: asp.net, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

Can someone tell any way to deploy different web.config on different EC2 instances with in same deployment group.

Scenario: We have few entries in the config that will be different on different instances. So need some way to update based on instance.

Comment: You can make it as part of your build process if your are building for each instance. You would use xml transforms to change the web.config per configuration. Or you can make it part of your deployment script and just swap the values prior to starting the service.

Comment: Hey Terry! I am a bit new on AWS. You have some way how we can associate variable with specific AWS instance. We have one build only and we want to change variable value on each instance it is deployed.

Comment: Are you using a script to deploy?

Comment: We are using power shell script to call New-CDDeployment from AWSPowerShell module.

Answer (score 1):

Create a script to make the necessary changes to your web.config and then use the hooks section of your app.spec file to run the script before install on your deployment. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks.html

Answer (score 1):

I actually took the approach of storing my web.config files for each environment in an S3 bucket.  As part of the CodeDeploy Deployment group process, it would download the config file from the S3 bucket in the After Install hook.  This way you can build the application once and push the same application files for each environment.  This also separates the configuration of the application from the actual code so that the development team doesn't need to know things like connection string values, etc...